# "Take smth over to" and the role of "over"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

"Now I'm gonna take these over to the cooker..."

This is being said  by a man, a chef, in a cooking video. "These" refers to meatballs on a cutting board lying in front of the chef. The cooker is behind him. So after saying that, the next moment he's going to turn away from the camera and step to the cooker with the cutting board in his hand.

My question is, what are other options for describing this movement, apart from "take these over to" (e.g. with "put" or "place")? Could you please give me some more examples of using "take smth over to" and explain the role of "over" in there?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Take X over to Y

means

> Take X from here to Y

It is an idiom.